# Creating a data-driven html webpage

Tags: jquery, mysql, html

Currently I am getting data from a mysql database using jquery, but I would like to know how to create content for my webpage based on the data that is received. For example, if I return a JSON object like { "options" : 3 }, then I would like to know how to respond accordingly in the HTML to create 4 list item.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    $('ul#optionsList').append('<li><a href="javascript:void(loadRand());">1.</a>          </li>');
        }
```

**jQuery Mobile ListView**

```
    <ul id="optionsList" data-role="listview" data-theme="g">
        </ul>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many possibilities how to create and modify DOM elements, here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SU9Uc/) example that populates unordered list

For more information about creating new elements [see](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-props)

And for better architecture of your page you might consider to use libraries such as [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) (with comprehensive beginner tutorial [here](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/))

Comment: +1 OP, make sure you are not transmitting any sensitive information via JSON object. Better solution IMO would be to use PHP. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256310/directly-accessing-server-database-via-ajax-without-php-or-some-other-intermedi)

Comment: @cek-cek your JSFiddle ex is great, however I'm using jQuery Mobile and the styling for my ListView disappears when I try to append using your code...I have edited my question above with the code I'm using.

Comment: After inserting new list items you have to call `$('ul#optionsList').listview('refresh');` to apply proper jQuery item styling. Here is jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xLmdw/

Answer (score 0):

If you required to built a huge html with your data, consider using templates.  handlerbars.js is a very good choice. http://handlebarsjs.com/